# Query regarding thread dead or leak

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-leaks

Suppose in my application one thread is executing the function say:

```
public void function(){
.
.
.
try{
//do something
}catch(Exception ex){
throw ex;
}

}
```

Now everytime the thread executes the function , it goes to catch block and then throw exception ex, and even parents function throws exception to its parent.
Now question is will my thread will die or this will cause thread leak in mu application?

Comment: just return dont throw anything thatll end the thread

Comment: The thread will stop execution when the `run()` method ends / returns irrespective of how the other methods it ahs called have ended. As far as resources are concerned, you need to handle (close) them manually.

Comment: So in this case , you mean thread will not die  out and will keep holding resource?

Comment: uncaught (or caught) exceptions dont alter the life cycle of you threads. The code will throw the exception and assuming you dont have a handler configured to catch it the system's default handler will print it to sys.out and exit the thread. Nothing dies out or gets killed. If you open some files or sockets in try but exception is thrown before closing it, you should use a finally block to close them. Imagine same situations in your main thread methods and the way you would handle them there, you should do it here as well.

Comment: @user3363969 - No, the thread will *Terminate* when *run* completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread will terminate *normally* except the problem would be it will not release any resources that it was holding when the exception occurred.

Example :

```
public class TryThreads {
static void someMethod() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("hello");
    throw new Exception();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Thread T = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getState());
            try {
                someMethod();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("still here");
        }

    });
    T.start();
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
    System.out.println(T.getState());
}
}
```

O/P:

```
RUNNABLE
hello
java.lang.Exception
    at TryThreads.someMethod(TryThreads.java:4)
    at TryThreads$1.run(TryThreads.java:15)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
still here
**TERMINATED** --> this line
```

Answer (score 0):

An exception that goes uncaught by the users code will eventually be thrown by the run() function of a thread. This causes the thread to terminate execution.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, a Thread is subject to garbage collection. There is no need (or way) to free (internal) resources manually.

You would create a Thread leak only if you accumulate the references to your threads and never free them. This means:

```
// cool, nobody references the thread, let the gc collect it when done
void foo() {
  Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable { ... });
  t.start();
}

// not cool, maybe set "t = null" some time
private Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable { ... });
void foo() {
  t.start();
}
```

Also note that there is no reason I could think of a JVM should keep its internal resources (e.g. a pthread_t) of a java.lang.Thread once it finished its purpose. So in general, there is nothing you should worry about in particular besides the JMM and manually managing a thread in the first place. Why don't you use an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)?

Comment: What about the resources that the thread opens, files, connections?. The JVM doesn't close them right?

Comment: Correct. You should use Java 7's try-with-resource statement for those. Also don't forget that you should close your resources even in single threaded code.

Answer (score 0):

The VM holds a thread control block (a small data structure) in memory for each non-daemon thread. This is not usually deleted until another thread "joins" the thread (i.e. issues a join() call against it to get the termination status, which is held in that control block). If your code doesn't clean these control blocks up by joining the threads then technically you have a resource leak. If the VM has a limited number of control blocks you could eventually use them all up.

The usual solution is to make your threads daemons before launching them. This basically tells the VM that you're not interested in the termination status and don't need to sync with the thread's termination by calling join(), and when they terminate the VM will clean up the control block for you.

Comment: Your statement is both wrong and dangerous. Especially the part about deamon threads. Note that the JVM does NOT have to execute finally blocks of deamon threads and no stacks are unwound. They will be simply killed when you exit the JVM. This is a very important detail.

Comment: In the case that the VM terminates, true - that happens when there are no more non-daemon threads, and daemon threads "die" with the VM process. However I was not under the impression that was the question here. Under normal running, the VM will always execute 'finally' blocks and handle exceptions in the same way as for non-daemon threads. Also thread objects might cause leaks if there are other references to them (someone already mentioned that in another answer). The point I was trying to make is that the VM can hold resources for non-daemon threads and your code needs to clean that up.

Comment: Can you point to that answer? And what kind of leaks are you talking about exactly? The resources the VM holds for a thread are unspecified and cannot be cleaned by you as a user. We are not talking about closeable resources. Heck, you could even register an UncaughtExceptionHandler and clean those at a different point.

Comment: Actually it was in your answer: "You would create a Thread leak only if you accumulate the references to your threads and never free them." As for the other part, we ran into a problem where a server application ran out of threads (i.e. couldn't create any more) because it wasn't "joining" old ones.

Comment: Yes. The object itself, like any other reference type which is subject to GC, would "leak" if you keep accumulating unnecessary references to it. If and how a Thread is implemented is simply not in the spec. You can even use green-threading in a JVM implementation.